# Email templates stopped working in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

All of the sudden email templates stopped working. Instead of template body we are getting below message

```
${SCRIPT,template="groovy-html-ps.template"}
```

We are loading script as mentioned below

```
    def content = '${SCRIPT,template="groovy-html-ps.template"}'
```

Our script is available in the same location but its not loading. Kindly help me to fix this.

Comment: You switch the quotes?

Comment: The provided code should always have produced the provided output. Is there some extra information missing?